# Zend 2 router setting

Tags: zend-framework, routes

Im very mew to **ZF2**, and cant figure out how to set the global router.
I know how to set on module level:

http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html says:

> The mapping of a URL to a particular action is done using routes that
>   are deﬁned in the module’s module.config.php file. We will add a route
>   for our album actions. This is the updated conﬁg file with the new
>   code commented.

```
// The following section is new and should be added to your file
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Is there a way to config a default behaviour for the whole application? Or i have to confing in each module?
**config/application.config.php** would be a logical place for it. Is it somewhere documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your ZF2 module defines in `getConfig()` gets merged with all the other module configs and eventually replaced by modules loaded afer it if some config keys collide. Thus your `getConfig()` already affects the entire application and its scope is not limited to your module only.